# How can I change the priority of a launchpad PPA?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on my server and want to install netatalk 2.2. There is a version available in the [PPA of Stefano Rivera](https://launchpad.net/~stefanor/+archive/ppa).

Now it happens that I've also got smartmontools installed for which he supplies a new version as well, but I'd really like to only upgrade netatalk.

I've tried adding the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/stefanor`:

```
Package: *
Pin: o=LP-PPA-stefanor
Pin-Priority: 50
```

but this hasn't changed anything.

How can I depriorize a repository and install just one piece of software from it?

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest you *ppa-purge* the PPA you want to default the software version back to the default lucid repository version.

Next, re-edit your software-sources (`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`) and remove the *#* from the PPA line-entry.

Run just an update - NOT an upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the software you want.

```
sudo apt-get install [software package]
```

Then re-open source-sources file and readd the *#* to the PPA so that no further updates are received.

For lucid, you can install *ppa-purge* by enabling the backports repository - again - do this from your software-sources file.

Comment: That seems like a crude workaround, with this setup it's impossible to automatically receive updates.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

Pin: release o=LP-PPA-stefanor

and check the priority by "apt-cache policy [package]"